# Browser crash when too much Audio objects are created in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, audio, crash

Hello i have a problem with my web application. I want to play  sounds when i hit  drum images so i create a new Audio Object inside my javascript.
I have an image in my html and onmousedown event i call the playSound function :

```
function playSound(soundfile) {
mysound = new Audio(soundfile);
mysound.play();}
```

After i hit the image too many times my Chrome browser crashes.
I tried to delete mysound object but the crash remains. I tested on firefox and there is no crash.

Anyone who can understand the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's an issue with Chrome itself. [Creating HTML5 audio elements crashes Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71322) which points to the current open issue: [Reduce the number of threads HTML5 audio/video elements use](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=61293)